# Mouseleave / Mouseout not triggered while using Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

as the topic states I came across a problem regarding Mouseleave / Mouseout Events being not triggered while using Chrome. This occurs if the div element the mouse is currently over is animated underneath while not moving the mouse itself. Even the pseudo class :hover is not removed. Fun fact: this works just fine when using Firefox.. whats up?

Here is the requested [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/r8rckL34/4/)

```
/*
    NOTE: DO NOT move the cursor after you have clicked the "animated" div and the 
    "mouseleave / mouseout" as well as the ":hover" pseudo class is not removed. That is, if you use Chrome as 
    a webbrowser...     
*/
var animated = $('.animated');

animated.on('mouseenter mouseover', null, null, function(e) {  
    $(this).html('mouseenter');
});

animated.on('mouseleave mouseout', null, null, function(e) {    
    $(this).html('mouseleave');
});

animated.on('click', null, null, function(e) {    
    $(this).animate({ 'margin-left': '20.0rem'}, { duration: 1000} ); 
});
```

Anyone experiences this and may have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Jan

Comment: "animated beneath and away" - I can only begin to interpret that.

Comment: Update your answer with code

Comment: Ok I will, thanks for the hint!

Comment: i am using chrome 38 for linux, and your jsfiddle example seems to work as expected for me (unless i am misunderstanding your problem description, which is probable). edit: oh, i see the problem now.

Comment: So Woodrow do you think it's a Chrome specific bug?